# Noise in a render with just emission

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, noise-reduction

In my render as seen is lots of noise in the background. But I only am using emission and transparent shaders (transparent at pure white). The noise only is visible in the final render, not if render in the viewport. The Sample count is the same for both viewport and render: 1. All bounces exept for Transparency are set to 0, since there would be nothing to bounce of.

[image]

I do not understand where the noise could be coming from.
I provided the Blend-File below.

[image]

Comment: Looks to me like you might have an extra copy of an object visible in the render but hidden in the viewport. Are their any viewport-hidden objects in the outliner?

Comment: That actually was the problem.